# How to check if movie clip or any of it's children lose focus in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, keyboard, focus

I have made custom Class for Input TextField with caption and own virtual keyboard which is loading in same MovieClip where TextField resides. And all works just fine. I wanted to remove keyboard from stage (from MovieClip stage) when user clicks on other visible input TextField, where new keyboard will be displayed.

If I check losing focus from MovieClip, wherever I click on keyboard (but not into Input TextField), it is closed because stage loose focus. Is there any way to check if any of children has no focus, so I can in that moment close the keyboard? In other word, to check if focus completely moved out from MovieClip stage to another.

Comment: Sorry ppl, I have found another solution, without checking focuses...

Comment: Please post a response with the solution that you've found so that other people with the same problem will benefit from it

Comment: I have Global class with static vars. When I select one field for editing, keyboard displayed and I set one variable, let's call it activeText to input text element. If I change to another input field without closing keyboard first I check if there is activeText variable set. If so, I just run script on that input box container to close keyboard, and then set new keyboard on newly selected input field. Not that click on input field has timer that waits about 0.1 sec before initiating keyboard, so removing keyboard and resetting variable activeText will be done before actual opening new one.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're just looking for [FocusEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/FocusEvent.html) In case you're need to check focus on MovieClip's children, you're have to attach listener to all of them.

Comment: No I haven't attach listeners to all of them, that would be too much, cause single main class have many children and children have own children... It would be just too complicated to check all of them every time. They are several "main classes" on screen, each have similar children subclasses with text input box in them and keyboard. There are too many items in one "main class" to check every single time. Anyway, I have moved out keyboard as a own class displaying just below selected input box.

Comment: for info, you can attach the `FocusEvent` to the main parent class, and just use the `target` to get your `TextField` (`e.target as TextField`)